# 'KNeighborsRegressor' object has no attribute 'cv_results_'

Tags: scikit-learn

Okay, so I know .cv_results_ object lies in the Grid and not in KNeighbor but I don't know how I should fit the grid model and not previous pipe line.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html), the attribute `cv_results_` does not exist for KNeighborsRegressor. You could, however, run a [`cross-validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) and get the `scores`.

Try this:

```
mod = KNeighborsRegressor()
cv_results = cross_validate(mod , X, y, cv=5)
cv_results['test_score']
```